# No voice output in simulator after update to 6.14

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

After updating the IDE yesterday to 6.14, I'm not getting any audio in the simulator. On-device testing is fine, and remains unchanged, so it doesn't seem to an issue with my capsule. This could be something coincidental on my end with hardware (running OSX).  Anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on OSX and running the latest version of the IDE:  Version 6.14.0-r19m.9478

Maybe take a look at your simulator and ensure you have the speaker turned on?

[image]

Comment: <embarrassed>Um, yep. That was it. </embarrassed>

Comment: No problem!  Thanks for posting here.  I'm sure others will run into this.